# Run pkill command in bash script. Script dead

Tags: python, bash, shell, devops

I am writing a Bash script that use pkill command.

Problem:

when `pkill <process>` command execute it kills the process and the script itself.

why the script killed?

any ideas?

Comment: Are the process you kill and the shell running the script related, i.e. do you kill a parent process of the shell?

Comment: Make sure the script doesn't have the same name as the process you're trying to kill.

Comment: not the same name and not related process.

Comment: Try using -x for exact matching